# How to turn on Wifi for Toshiba Satellite E305

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

I can't figure out how to turn the wifi back on... I've been to Google with no luck and can't even find a product manual.  Can someone please help me figure this out?  Here's the page on [Toshiba's web site](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/e305):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Toshiba Satellite E305, if all your drivers are installed properly, and nothing is disabled unnaturally, pressing <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> on your keyboard should enable or disable the built in wireless adapter.

That is from chapter 4, page 127 of the user manual, which can be found on the Toshiba Support site:

[Satellite E305 User Manual](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/downloads/GMAD00268010_SatE300_10Dec08_updated082411.pdf) :)

Comment: Can you link me to the manual please?  I wasn't able to hunt it down :-\

Comment: see the edits above